# Are there any feats themed like Rime Spell, but for other elements?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, metamagic

Are there any feats themed like [Rime Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/rime-spell-metamagic/), but for other elements? The effect doesn’t have to entangle, but something caused by the element.

Only official Paizo sources please.

Comment: Are you only interested in metamagic feats which apply to spells based on an *elemental* descriptor/damage (e.g. [fire] or [acid]), or would feats themed on other spell descriptors (such as [darkness] or [light]) be of interest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, there are a few of them

Those feats are mostly from [Ultimate Magic](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8k8r?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Ultimate-Magic), and though you can find those (and many more) on the [metamagic feats](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/) list on the SRD, here are those directly related to the elemental damage types:

- [Burning Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/burning-spell-metamagic) (+2), will cause the target of a fire or acid spell to take additional damage the next round;
- [Flaring Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/flaring-spell-metamagic) (+1) causes the target of an electricity, fire or light spell to be dazzled for a few rounds;
- [Concussive Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/concussive-spell-metamagic) (+2) will cause the target of a sonic spell to take a penalty on attacks, skill checks and ability checks for a few rounds;
- [Toppling Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/toppling-spell-metamagic) (+1) will cause the target of a force spell to fall prone.